# ListView of ONLY drawables

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a dynamic array of drawables and want to display them in a scrollable list. The thing I am having the most trouble with is the array adapter. I don't get any compile time errors with this code, but the runtime error I get is -

```
Process: com.example.michael.myandroidappactivity, PID: 12297
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

I don't want to use a textview though! Here's the main code-

```
public class cards extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_old_cards);
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.showCardList);
    cardPile tmp = cardPile.getInstance();
    ArrayList<Integer> discardPile = tmp.getDiscardPile();
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> imgAdapt = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,R.layout.listview_layout,discardPile);
    list.setAdapter(imgAdapt);
}
```

}

Comment: You need to override the getView of ArrayAdapter

Comment: You will need to create your own custom subclass of `ArrayAdapter`, where you override `getView()` and handle the row layout inflation and widget population yourself.

Comment: Baseadapter instead of arrayadapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new class that extends the `BaseAdapter` interface and modify the `getView` method to return the view you want to show in your `ListView`. For example:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Integer> imagesIds;

public ImageAdapter(Context _context, ArrayList<Integer> _imageIds)
{
    context = _context;
    imageIds = _imageIds;
}


@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return imgIds.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return null; 
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ImageView view;

    if( convertView != null ) // recycle call
    {
        view = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    else
    {
        view = new ImageView(context);
        image.setBackgroundResource(imageIds.get(position));
    }

    return view;
}
}
```

Then modify your listView adapter as:

```
list.setAdapter( new ImageAdapter( this, discardPile) );
```

Comment: How can I use the xml layout I have set up for each ListView item instead of setting up the ImageView drawable in the code? The above worked by the way!! Thank you.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved the original question. If you want to use an `ImageView` layout already defined make the context member of type `Activity` and then use `view = context.findViewById( R.id.yourId )` instead of `view = new ImageView(context)`. If that's not what you were looking for, create a new question with your xml so we can help you better.